# Phonegap orientation

Tags: javascript, cordova, ios7

My app only works in landscape mode due to some layout restrictions. Since IOS7 update, whenever I take a photo on my phonegap app, the right hand side of the screen disappears (as if the orientation changes to portrait) and I'm left with a black bar down the right hand side.

If I rotate the ipad 180˚ it resets itself and displays properly again but my client will not accept this as a solution!

Any ideas why it is happening? or how I could programatically change the orientation?

Comment: I can add that having detected the orientation and screen dimensions, the orientation stays correct (90) but the screen dimensions change to 768 x 1024 (portrait)

Comment: I meant 748 x 1024 which is the correct dimensions for portrait

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the black bar on right side. My problem occurred when the orientation changed, not from the camera. For me the solution was to change the viewport meta tag in index.html to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

For anyone doing any digging, I found that the webView was resizing correctly, and the black bar was from the webView not re-rendering its content at the correct size.